# UITableViewCell height incorrect until cells are recreated by scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tried setting `cell.setNeedsLayout()` and calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` in every place where I modify the contents of the cell, but no matter what the cell height is incorrect until I scroll down/up.

**Incorrect (initial load):**

[image]

**Correct (after scrolling):**

[image]

***cellForRowAtIndexPath*:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OMCFeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OMCFeedTableViewCell
    let p = posts[indexPath.row]

    cell.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
    cell.profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    cell.profileImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "profile_blank")

    let API = userAPI()
    API.getByID(p.postEntity) {
        (result: User?) in

        if let u = result {
            cell.profileName.text = u.name

            let uploads = uploadAPI()
            uploads.tryGetImage(u.image) {
                (result: UIImage?) in

                if let i = result {
                    cell.profileImage.image = i
                }
                cell.setNeedsLayout()
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    let data = p.content!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let content = try! JSON(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers))

    if let image = content["image"].string {
        let uploads = uploadAPI()
        uploads.tryGetImage(image) {
            (result: UIImage?) in

            if let i = result {
                let oFrame = cell.postImage.frame
                let width = oFrame.width
                let height = (i.size.height / i.size.width) * width
                cell.postImageHeight.constant = height
                cell.postImageHeight.priority = 999
                cell.postImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                cell.postImage.image = i
            } else {
                cell.postImageHeight.priority = 1
                cell.postImage.image = nil
            }
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    } else {
        cell.postImage.image = nil
        cell.postImageHeight.constant = 0
    }

    cell.postText.text = ""
    if let text = content["text"].string {
        cell.postText.text = text
    }

    cell.postTimestamp.text = JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.sharedFormatter().attributedTimestampForDate(p.timestamp).string
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is your constraint like?

Comment: @FarhadNežad Everything is constrained to the sides of the superview along with margin constraints to the items above and below

Comment: what's inside your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: if you have different height for each cell you should set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and
 `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = someValue` and make sure your constraints are properly placed. here [http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift] is a tutorial.

Comment: @Lucho that's exactly what I have

Comment: @Lucho I think the cell do that already take a look at both cells. they're different size.

Comment: @teamnorge I don't have one since I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: @ErikJohnson Remove the margin constraint.

Comment: @FarhadNežad removing the bottom margin constraint on the imageview completely broke everything, was I supposed to remove a different one?

Comment: @FarhadNežad Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

Comment: Okay, but is the image in right size?

Comment: @FarhadNežad nope: see here http://postimg.org/image/rsrbb6dcl/

Comment: i did the same in a recent project, i don't call ` cell.setNeedsLayout() ` and `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` with constraints should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are updating the contents of your table cell (and hence it's height) after it's been displayed, the table view won't notice it. You need to tell it about it.

You may try `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, not sure if that's enough.

Comment: Just curious how to convert that to Swift syntax. Thanks :)

Comment: self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

Comment: @jcaron OK doing that gives me the correct row height! But there's one problem: The old content is above the image. See here: http://postimg.org/image/o2akg5mhf/

Comment: Not sure what part of the display is part of what row in your picture, but you may need to update your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to make sure that if you have already loaded the data, it does not try to load it asynchronously, but provides the good, final layout right away.

Comment: @jcaron I fixed that issue... Now I'm using beginUpdates / endUpdates which works fine until I try to scroll up and I get a crash with NSRangeException. I'll try some more stuff and post again when I run into more problems. Thanks!